# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference Exception with var type

Tags: c#, api, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to fetch data from CRM using this API. I get an error

> Runtime binding on a null reference

whenever I try to get value from `data.fullname`. Is there any way I can fix it?

Thanks

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("contacts?$select=fullname,emailaddress1").Result;
           
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var accounts = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var jRetrieveResponse = JObject.Parse(accounts);

    dynamic collContacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jRetrieveResponse.ToString());

    try
    {
        foreach (var data in collContacts.value)
        {
            // You can change as per your need here
            if (data.fullname.Value != null)
            {
                success[i] = data.fullname.Value;
            }

            i ++;
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { 
         throw; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide information about where exactly does the error occur in the code, and the exact library used?

Comment: FYI: `catch (Exception) { throw; }` is the same behavior as not having a `try/catch` in the first place. May as well remove the redundant code.

Comment: Can you show the json output?

Comment: async with `.Result;` which makes it blocking. What is the problem with async code?

Comment: Check if the `data.fullname` is null before you access the `Value` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if (data.fullname.Value != null)
```

with this

```
if  (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.fullname.Value))
```

OR Replace

```
try
{
    foreach (var data in collContacts.value)
    {
        // You can change as per your need here
        if (data.fullname.Value != null)
        {
            success[i] = data.fullname.Value;
        }

        i ++;
    } 
}
catch (Exception)
{ 
     throw; 
}
```

With

```
try
{
    foreach (var data in collContacts.value)
    {
        success[i] = data?.fullname?.Value;
        i ++;
    } 
}
catch (Exception)
{ 
     throw; 
}
```